# How to change the permission sets via Apex

Tags: apex

On Account Object there is a lookup field  callled as 'AccountManager' where I can assign the user(Lookup(User)). 
Now  there is a tab called as "Account Team "(Under the Account) where I can add multiple users which I can modify.
Suppose A is the user who creates an account then he can add and modify the "Account Team " members.
and in the 'AccountManager'field if I add the user as 'B'.when I login to the application as B and navigating to the perticular account that was created by A then B can see the Account Team Member(Read Only) but can not add or delete it.

I have a requirement inwhich if any user who creates an account and add the user in 'AccountManager' field then Account Manager should  modify the team members.

I know with manually it is possible but i am looking for a programatical way like writing an apex class then call its method in trigger.
It would be better if I get any example

I am new in Apex Programming &Following code I am trying to write

```
public with sharing class AssignPermissionSet{

   public static void assignPermission(List<PermissionSetAssignment> preset ){
   //List<Account> Acc=[Select id, name, type,AccountManager__c, RecordType.Name FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name ='Account Group'];
     List<PermissionSet> per=[SELECT Id,Name, PermissionsModifyAllData FROM PermissionSet];

     List<User> u=[select id,name from user where id IN (select AccountManager__c from Account) ];
 preset=[ SELECT AssigneeId,Id,PermissionSetId,PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment where AssigneeId =:u AND PermissionSetId =:per];

     List<ObjectPermissions> op = [SELECT Id,ParentId,SobjectType,PermissionsRead,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsDelete,PermissionsCreate FROM ObjectPermissions where SobjectType='Account' AND ParentId=:per ];        
   }
}
```

This is just a rough code I am trying to write.
need a help how how to update the existing Permission Set where I can assign Create,Delete,edit permission to the Account Manager user.In our application every user must have at least one permission sets.

Answer (score 0):

This approach you are suggesting will not work as you are talking about record level access and not object level. This mainly has to do with the Org wide defaults and sharing settings.

You would need to create the [**AccountShare**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountshare.htm) object and provide read/write access to the Account Manager for the record in context. He can then modify the Account Team Members.

```
AccountShare share = new AccountShare();
share.AccountId = '<yourAccountId>';

//Set the user Id to share the accounts with
share.UserOrGroupId = '<AccountManagerId>';

share.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
share.CaseAccessLevel = 'Edit';
share.AccountAccessLevel='Edit';
```

Comment: instead of updating the existing permission.I have create a new custom permission set and provide the access that I want to give.Now I am writing an apex code where I am assigning the custom permission to the user.I have modified the code as follow

Comment: List<PermissionSetAssignment> p=new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
PermissionSet per=[SELECT Id,Name FROM PermissionSet where Name='Key_Acc_Manager_Custom_Attributes'];List<User> u=[select id,name,(Select Id from PermissionSetAssignmentsWhere PermissionSetID = :per.id)from user where id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
List<Account> Acc=[Select Id,Name,RecordType.Name,KeyAccountManager__c from Account where KeyAccountManager__c =:u ];if(u[0].PermissionSetAssignments.size() == 0){p.add( new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = u.Id,PermissionSetId = per.Id) );System.debug('Value of P:'+p);}insert p;

Comment: Permission Sets/ Profiles provide access at object level, not record level.

Comment: If add the method mentioned by you tehn it throws me an error Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [AccountShare].setAccountAccessLevel(String).Is there any way where I can avoid this error and call the methods directly

Comment: Updated the answer. Those methods were from SOAP API.. In Apex you can simply use the field names available on AccountShare object

Comment: there is limitation of AccountShare object is I can not assign ModifyAll permission because in my use case there is Related List called as "Account Team" where I am trying to assign edit,delete,create permission to teh Key Manager but it is only possible via modify all as it is related object..So the scenario that u suggested is not applicable in my use case as I can not assign view/modify all permission via apex.Do u have any other suggession where I can give permission to related list object?

Comment: I have tried the other way via custom permission but yes it is giving me teh object level  access that I dont wanna give..But is there any logic that i can apply like once I insert the permission then after the fulfilling functionality I can rollback/delete the permission.I think via delete it is possible but again What wevent should I Suppose to trigger that is difficult to think..